# Delphi Generics: cannot cast class and constructor constrained generic type to an interface

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

```
procedure Test<TType: class, constructor>;

procedure TTestClass.Test<TType>;
var
   Obj1: IInterface;
begin
   Obj1 := TType.Create as IInterface;
end;
```

Gives the following compile error:

> [DCC Error] TestCNCTypesSerialization.pas(76): E2015 Operator not
>   applicable to this operand type

I do not understand why. And I cannot find a way to make this work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no grounds to believe that the generic type implements `IInterface`. You did not constrain the generic type to be derived from a class that implements `IInterface`.

You could constrain the class in that way, but that might be too restrictive. Alternatively use `Supports` to obtain the interface.

Comment: Strangely enough using Supports works now. I had tried that but received this error consistently:  F2084 Internal error : URW1147. I don't think anything major has changed though.
I would have preferred to not use Supports, since then I do not need to Free the created objects. But no matter how I declare the class constraint it will not let me cast TType to an interface...

Comment: You'd have to constrain the type to be derived from a class that implemented an interface